# Speeding up adding files to PHAR

Tags: php, performance, phar

To add files to a PHAR archive, you call [`Phar::addFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.addfile.php) for every file you want to add to the PHAR file.

However, when adding a lot of files to a PHAR (sidenote: "PHAR Archive" or just "PHAR"?), PHAR creation slows down dramatically. I used the following script to measure the time it took PHP to create a PHAR containing 100 one-megabyte (1 000 000 byte) files stored in a "Files" subdirectory.

```
<?php

$pathStat = "pharstat.csv";
$pathPhar = "phar.phar";

if (file_exists($pathPhar)) {
    unlink($pathPhar);
}

$stat = new SplFileObject($pathStat, "w");

$phar = new Phar($pathPhar);
$phar->startBuffering();

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__ . "/Files");

$start = microtime(true);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->getFilename() != "." && $file->getFilename() != "..") {
        $phar->addFile($file->getPathname(), $file->getFilename());

        echo "Added " . $file->getPathname() . "\r\n";

        $split = microtime(true);
        $stat->fwrite(number_format($split - $start, 6) . "\r\n");
    }
}

$phar->stopBuffering();

?>
```

The script gets the split time every time a file is added to the PHAR and outputs its to a "pharstat.csv" file for analysis.

[Here is a link to the data I got. Feel free to peer-review my results.](http://www.filedropper.com/pharstat)

The data confirmed that adding files to a PHAR gets slower the more files are already in the PHAR. Furthermore, the data suggested that the time to add *n* files into a PHAR grows by *n*².

I did a quick experiment with Java's ZIP creation utilities, and it seems that PHP PHAR is unique in its *n*² behavior.

So the question is: why is PHAR this slow? And is there anyway to speed it up, ideally towards an *n* behavior?

Comment: I'd say it's just PHAR however [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.php) seems to disagree.